# Why calling env() function directly in controllers does not work?

Tags: laravel

Supporting Laravel 6.20 app, I see a lot of `env()` methods called in the controllers.
It does not work on my side, so I made a wrapper in the config/app.php file, and using it made it work.
And I have to make a lot of similar changes in the app to make it work properly...

But looks like that `env()`  worked for my client on live and developers server.
I know that calling `env()`  in controllers directly is a bad way but wonder why it worked on servers?
Are there some common PHP configurations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have probably cached your configurations by running `php artisan config:cache`

according to the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#optimizing-configuration-loading)

> This command will combine all of Laravel's configuration files into a single, cached file, which greatly reduces the number of trips the framework must make to the filesystem when loading your configuration values.

and then

> If you execute the `config:cache` command, you should be sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within your configuration files. Once the configuration has been cached, the `.env` file will not be loaded and all calls to the `env` function for `.env` variables will return `null`.

you have to just run `php artisan config:clear` and this will clear the cache file. you will be able to get the `env` values again.

but yeah don't use any values directly from `.env` files. there are some issues. to get more performance, cache the configs. so wrap the `env` value in a config key like in `config/app.php`

```
'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel')
```

you are saying that use the `APP_NAME` key from the `env` file as your laravel app name and if there's no `APP_NAME` key or value in `env` use `Laravel` as default.

secondly if you make some requests within a very short period of time, like page loads and you are calling some xmlhttp requests at the same time, there's possibility of not getting the `env` values (returns `null`) if you have to use any. this is a php bug. so read `env` values from config files with a default value for performance and for avoiding bug.

Comment: Yes, I know how caching works in laravel, I really wonder how it worked for my client. It is the second time I encounter such case and have to apply changes to make it working on my OS

Comment: it's all about cache issue. i don't think OS plays any role here.